# Windows redirects folders shares

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing, windows-server-2012-r2, hosts-file, credentials

I don't know if I'm writing my question in the right place, but, here it goes.

My company owns a Windows Server 2012 R2 which shares some folders through our network. We're trying to access it outside the company. To do it, we used the hosts file.
The problem is that, when I try to access the server outside here with my login, possibly because I have the same login in more than one computer in the domain, Windows seems to be 'confused' and redirects one PC to another.
Ex.: The server is named by SL. The other PC is called SL2. So, when I try to access `\\SL2` at my home (with the same password/login and the hosts file correctly setted up), my PC goes to SL server. I already tried to erase windows credentials, but the mistake persists.
Does anybody know how to erase this configuration from my PC in order to try the correct access again?

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but a question of this nature would probably be more appropriate at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Do both servers have their own public IP addresses, or are you connecting through a VPN? Why are you using the hosts file?

Comment: @grawity Yes, both servers have their own public IP adresses. And I'm using the hosts file because it was, supposedly, the simplest way to connect all of our devices, according to our internet technician.

Comment: Does the issue still happen if you access the servers by their IP address (e.g. `\\1.2.3.4`)?

Comment: Outside office yes (but then I believe it's because of the Public IP), but, if the PC is in the same network of the devices, it understands its internal IP's.